# How To Set Initial Camera Position To The Current Device's Latitude and Longitude Using Google Maps For Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I am using google maps flutter plugin for my App. I want the initial camera position target (the LatLng) to be exactly equal to the current device's latitude and longitude so that the camera on startup shows where the user currently is. However, I am running into issues trying to do this. I have tried using the Location and Geolocator packages but there is no clear cut example on how to do what I want to achieve.

When I try to use `currentLocation.latitude` and `currentLocation.longitude` for the Location package as the values for the Latlng in the camera target I am running into the below error.

> "only static members can be accessed by initializers"

Frankly I don't know what that means in this context. I have read some examples but none clearly implements what I really want to achieve

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';


class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Map> createState() => MapState();
}

class MapState extends State<Map> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  var currentLocation = LocationData;

  var location = new Location();

 Future _getLocation() async {
    try {
      location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
        print('Latitude:${currentLocation.latitude}');
        print('Longitude:${currentLocation.longitude}');
        return LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
      });
    } catch (e) {
     print('ERROR:$e');
      currentLocation = null;
    }

  }
  static final CameraPosition _currentPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude  ,  currentLocation.longitude),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getLocation();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition: _currentPosition,
        zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
        tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),

    );
  }


}
```

That is my code snippet producing the error on the _currentPosition final which represents Camera position am equating it to current device's latitude and longitude using locator package but Flutter is complaining. I don't know how to do it correctly. I want the latlng target to be the latlng of the device

Answer (score 26):

The issue concerning the error when displaying the map widget while getting the user current location is that, getting the user's actual current location is an asynchronous operation and thus the during that whole process initial position will be null thus we make a conditional that runs as we wait for the async operation to complete then display the map when then the value will be non-null. I have refactored the code and used the geolocator package instead

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapState createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> controller1;

  //static LatLng _center = LatLng(-15.4630239974464, 28.363397732282127);
  static LatLng _initialPosition;
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  static  LatLng _lastMapPosition = _initialPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserLocation();
  }
  void _getUserLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    List<Placemark> placemark = await Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    setState(() {
      _initialPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
      print('${placemark[0].name}');
    });
  }


  _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      controller1.complete(controller);
    });
  }

  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  void _onMapTypeButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _currentMapType = _currentMapType == MapType.normal
          ? MapType.satellite
          : MapType.normal;
    });
  }

  _onCameraMove(CameraPosition position) {
    _lastMapPosition = position.target;
  }

  _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(
          Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(_lastMapPosition.toString()),
              position: _lastMapPosition,
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                  title: "Pizza Parlour",
                  snippet: "This is a snippet",
                  onTap: (){
                  }
              ),
              onTap: (){
              },

              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker));
    });
  }
  Widget mapButton(Function function, Icon icon, Color color) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: function,
      child: icon,
      shape: new CircleBorder(),
      elevation: 2.0,
      fillColor: color,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _initialPosition == null ? Container(child: Center(child:Text('loading map..', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Avenir-Medium', color: Colors.grey[400]),),),) : Container(
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            markers: _markers,

            mapType: _currentMapType,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: _initialPosition,
              zoom: 14.4746,
            ),
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
            myLocationEnabled: true,
            compassEnabled: true,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: false,

          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    mapButton(_onAddMarkerButtonPressed,
                        Icon(
                            Icons.add_location
                        ), Colors.blue),
                    mapButton(
                        _onMapTypeButtonPressed,
                        Icon(
                          IconData(0xf473,
                              fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.iconFont,
                              fontPackage: CupertinoIcons.iconFontPackage),
                        ),
                        Colors.green),
                  ],
                )),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GeoLocator API has been changed with latest upgraded Geolocator is no longer used. Instead GeolocatorPlatform is new keyword to access current postion as per latest updates

```
LatLng currentPostion;

void _getUserLocation() async {
        var position = await GeolocatorPlatform.instance
            .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    
        setState(() {
          currentPostion = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        });
      }
```

Use currentPostion in your googlemap. (define Latlag currentPosition);

```
GoogleMap(
             // onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
             initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
               target: currentPostion,
               zoom: 10,
             ),  
           ),
```

Comment: this worked for me ``Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)``

Answer (score 1):

The error you mentioned implies that you are trying to access a non-static variable inside the initializer, which is in your case `currentLocation`.

Since the value of `currentLocation` will be different for each instance of the `MapState` class, you are getting the above error.

Remove the `static` and `final` keywords and try setting the `_currentPosition` variable inside the `initState` function as below -

```
class MapState extends State<Map> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  var currentLocation = LocationData;

  var location = new Location();
  CameraPosition _currentPosition;

  Future _getLocation() async {
    try {
      location.onLocationChanged().listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
        print('Latitude:${currentLocation.latitude}');
        print('Longitude:${currentLocation.longitude}');
        return LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
      });
    } catch (e) {
     print('ERROR:$e');
      currentLocation = null;
    }

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getLocation();
    currentPosition = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude  ,  currentLocation.longitude),
      zoom: 14.4746,
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  //Rest of the code remains same
}
```

Comment: I am now getting the errors "The getter latitude and longitude not defined for the Class 'Type' "

Comment: I have dealt with that error by doing like so 'CameraPosition _currentPosition;' However, your solution brings about the error "The getter latitude was called on null", its a 'noSuchMethodError:'

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be because you are just passing the reference of `LocationData` to `currentLocation` instead of instantiating the object. Try using `var currentLocation = LocationData();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some updates have been made in the Geolocator package and flutter handling, therefor I've updated the code by Mohd Danish Khan.

The best option to do afterward is to have a ternary operation on ***_initialPosition != null*** to check if the map should be rendered or if you should render a message or empty container

```
LatLng? _initialPosition;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _getUserLocation();
}

void _getUserLocation() async {
  var position = await GeolocatorPlatform.instance.getCurrentPosition(
    locationSettings: const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation));

  setState(() {
    _initialPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **latlong2**

You must import it as

```
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as latlong;
```